# Implementing TypeInformation in Flink for a class with an interface field

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a fairly nested data type that comes into flink over a Kafka topic. The JSON is deserialized into a Java class hierarchy that uses interfaces (together with JsonSubTypes, see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-polymorphic-type-handling-annotations) in a number of places. My plan was to use TypeInformation.createSerializer to use Json SerDe on this type within Flink. 2 things are concerning me though:

1. I have no idea what to return for getArity and getTotalFields. Am hoping to return 1 for both. I have tested this and it seems to be ok but have no idea if this will cause a problem down the road.
2. Is it sufficient to write a serializer / deserializer for the top object in the hierarchy or do I need to write SerDe for each class in the hierarchy. How can I tell if Flink is going to save this class in the state? I hope it only persists classes of the Type of the parameter of the DataStream<...>. Is this the case?

**Edit 1**

As the messages that are coming in over Kafka are also the main types used within my Flink program I am trying to unite the SerDe. Why I want to do this was not part of the question but it is related to state schema migrations and Kryo compatibility problems caused by the JsonSubTypes part of the message above.

I have one place where I maintain my own State:

```
    val stateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<>(
            "RulesBroadcastState",
            new StringSerializer(),
            new RuleTypeSerializer());
```

RuleTypeSerializer is of Type TypeSerializer and uses Jackson as detailed above. This is working fine.

The rest of the flink program uses a number of stateful operations / keyed state. My understanding is that the only way to get Flink to use custom SerDe for such state is to use @TypeInfo which takes a TypeInfoFactory which instantiates a TypeInformation.

That's the context of my question regarding implementing TypeInformation. Maybe there is an alternative way to get Flink to use a custom serializer?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but hopefully a solution to your problem:

1. deserialize the JSON to a POJO with corresponding fields, e.g. for JSON messages like `{"name": "Snowball", "species": "dog", "age": 3}` (loosely inspired by that Jackson link with animals) you'd deserialize to a class `Animal` with fields `String name`, `String species`, `int age`. You can use one of the many "UTF-8 bytes to POJO" libraries out there for this, such as `jsoniter`. Be liberal with what you accept, capture as much data as you can, and set suitable "the field was not present" defaults - you do NOT want to throw exceptions (see below).
2. this will create a `DataStream[Animal]`, to which you can `.flatmap` or `.process` with additional code as needed that converts `Animal` to its subtypes.

I know that's effectively what the custom JSON deserializer you want to develop would do, just in two separate steps instead of one. But I recommend doing it the above way for a number of reasons:

1. Rolling your own `TypeInformation` is difficult - the documentation isn't very instructive as you've found, and there aren't any good guides on it. I've been there! What I realized was even if I got it to work, it would be a risk to really rely on an implementation that I don't fully understand and can't support if it goes down.
2. The `TypeInformation` deserializer is used in the lower levels of Flink's tech stack, around the `StreamTask` level, where you can't trap exceptions. So if a serdes failure occurs then your task will crash. If you have automatic retries, then you'll repeatedly restart and crash in a loop
3. But if you have a don't-throw-exceptions policy in your serdes code and deserialize everything with the `TypeInformation`, then you can add all the complex handling and trap all the exceptions you want in a user-defined function like `FlatmapFunction` or `ProcessFunction`. There you have more flexibility: you can trap exceptions, you can make the output `Optional`, have access to side outputs and your logging framework

In short, you move the hard work of deserializing input data to polymorphic subtypes from a relatively inaccessible place deep in Flink's stack to an easily accessed operator you have full control over. My experience wrangling with terabytes of financial data in Flink taught me that there WILL be serdes issues in production, you WILL have schema evolution as you develop, and you NEED simple recipes for handling them. Relying on a framework (`TypeInformation` internals, Jackson's subtypes, etc.) introduces a lot of details and constraints outside your control.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed reply! I can't quite match that up with what I am trying to do. Deserializing the messages that come in over Kafka is not the problem. It is the SerDe for the internal state that I am trying to change. I'll adapt the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I think I understand it now. For keyed states, one solution we used, about 80% of the time, was to change `Rule` so Flink makes a TypeInformation with better serde performance. Usually by making it a POJO somehow. The other 20% of the time we made a "delegating" TypeSerializer. In particular, check out Flink's String serializer. Then you can make a TypeSerializer[Rule] by using Jackson to de/serialize from/to a String, then delegate to Flink's TypeSerializer[String].

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying but the question is how to get Flink to use this TypeSerializer to serialize keyed state?

Comment: It's the part in your edit with the `MapStateDescriptor` interface - make an instance of your custom serializer, then create your map state with it: `new MapStateDescriptor(stateName, valueSerializer, new RuleTypeSerializer())`. `RuleTypeSerializer` would be your custom subtype of `TypeSerializer<Rule>` that either implements all the methods yourself, or an implementation with a private Flink `StringSerializer` where you use Jackson to convert your `Rule`s to `String`, then call `StringSerializer`'s methods to handle the string.